# Render static files in /doc in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So far I have in `config/routes.rb`:

```
match 'doc/:path' => 'doc#show'
```

And in `app/controllers/doc_controller.rb`:

```
class DocController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def show
    render File.join( RAILS_ROOT, 'doc', params[:path] )
  end
end
```

This works find for `index.html` and other `.html` files. But it doesn't serve up `.css` and `.js` files. It also doesn't serve nested files and directories such as `/doc/metrics/output/index.html`

How can I get Rails to serve up all static files in `/doc` but without simply putting a link to them in `/public` (so that I can autheticate the user in the controller first)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not serving the files through Rails at all. Serve them through your server (Nginx, Apache).  You can use the X-Accel-Redirect and the X-Sendfile headers to tell Nginx and Apache to send the static file instead.  The benefit of this approach is that you can still authenticate a user before allowing them access to the file.  Here's the Nginx tutorial:

http://ablogaboutcode.com/2010/11/19/serving-static-files-passenger-nginx/

Another option is to setup your routes like this:

```
match 'doc' => 'doc#show'
```

And pass your path as a parameter so you don't have to do nested URL matching in your routes, or handle special cases (.css, .js, .html, ...)

```
/doc?path=/path/to/my/document.css
```

Comment: I believe X-Sendfile will work in some form on Heroku.  I would recommend checking their documentation and help.

Comment: You might want to try the alternative route structure then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would also mean rewritting all the urls in Yardoc and Metric_fu generated files. I had hoped there would be an easier way to do this.

Comment: There may be a meta-programming way around it, but Rails treats '/' as a separator in routes, so you can't match URLs with it as far as I know.

Comment: I decided to go with a symbolic link. I don't know if this will work in Heroku yet, but it works great in development where I use it most.