# Rails: NameError on nonexistent RAILS_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, nameerror

This is really bizarre. I was following one the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889200/render-static-files-in-doc-in-rails) just to test things out. I couldn't get it to work out, so I just deleted it. I just have this now:

```
class DocController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
end
```

I refreshed the page and still had an `uninitialized constant DocController::RAILS_ROOT` on line 7. I do not have a line 7, it ends at 5. So I decided to put `puts "alskjdfal;ksdjfa;lkdsjf"` on line 7, and my controller file then ended at line 8. It still said that the error came from line 7. I deleted the controller, but left the route in, and it still says the error comes from line 7. I know it isn't that I'm working on the wrong file, because I can see the changes I make on the error page.

[image]

So I figure it's something in the background, but when I tell git to drop all my changes, it still happens, and git says there is nothing different in my files. When I switch to my master branch, which has none of this business, after I add `get 'doc/index'` to the master `routes.rb`, I get this same error.

Where is it coming from, and how can I get rid of it? Please and thank you.

Comment: `Rails.root.join('doc/index')` work for you?

Comment: Nope... same error comes up, even when there's no controller.

Comment: Did you replace the `RAILS_ROOT` constant with what I suggested, or add it?

Comment: I added what you suggested on line 7, where the complaint is regardless of if `RAILS_ROOT` is there.